# If the domain of a bijection is complete, the image is also complete?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $f:A\mapsto B$ be a bijective mapping. May I state that when the domain $A$ of $f$ is complete, its image $B$ is also complete?

Comment: What do you mean by "complete" ?

Comment: Complete means that every Cauchy Sequence is convergent

Comment: So, you're essentially asking whether if $A,B$ be two metric spaces with $A$ complete and $f\colon A\to B$ is a bijection, then $B$ is also a complete metric space, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly this.

Comment: This is true if $f$ is an [isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry) (i.e., a distance preserving bijection). For the proof, see [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Metric_Space_Completeness_is_Preserved_by_Isometry). Can you think of a counterexample when $f$ is just a bijection? (hint: consider a bijection that doesn't preserve distance)

Comment: Take your favorite noncomplete metric space $Y$; let $X$ be the same set as $Y$, but with the discrete metric. The identity, considered as a map $X\to Y$,  is a bijection, but the domain is complete and the codomain isn't. Note that the map is even continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Consider the metric spaces $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb Q$ endowed with the usual metric.

Since $\Bbb Q$ is countable, we have a bijection $f\colon\Bbb N\to\Bbb Q$

But $\Bbb N$ is complete whereas $\Bbb Q$ is not (it is dense in $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$), so consider a sequence of rationals converging to, say $\pi$, thus showing it is not complete).

Comment: This is a non-constructive (existential) answer that shows that you don't really need to explicitly construct a non-isometry to disprove the claim, just showing the existence of a bijection between two metric spaces, one complete and the other not does the work.